# Key-value pair order in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When applying a function such as `reduceByKey`, is there any way to specify a key other than the first element of the tuple?

My current solution consists in using a `map` function to rearrange the tuple in the correct order by I assume that this additional operation comes at a computational cost, right?

Comment: In my experience the computational cost is minimal of a simple map. This map is pretty trivial compared to the day-to-day ways I use map, flatMap, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `reduceByKey`, you need a key-value `RDD[K,V]` where `K` is the key that will be used. If you have a `RDD[V]` you need to perform a `map` first to specify the key.

```
myRdd.map(x => (x, 1))
```

If you already have a `RDD[K,V]` where the key is not what you want... You need another `map`. There is no other way to get around this. For instance, if you want to switch between your key and your value, you could do the following:

```
myPairRdd.map(_.swap)
```

Comment: Tuple2 has a swap method, so the map can be map(_.swap)

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure there was no method that allowed me to select what element of the tuple to act as key. It would probably be a useful improvement since it allows avoiding an additional map.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the compare function and call to `sortByKey`:

```
implicit val sortFunction = new Ordering[String] {
  override def compare(a: String, b: String) = // compare function
}

val rddSet: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(dataSet)

rddSet.sortByKey()
```

Comment: I think that his problem is not how the data is sorted, he wants `reduceByKey` to use as `K` something that is in the `V` part.

Comment: If @eirasf needs the RDD results in a non standard order, this is one of the possible ways we can use to do it. I wouldn't compute on my own the order of the computation as I prefer to leave Spark distributing the load as it wants. But if we need the result in a particular format, I think it should be a post processing step.